# Route53 change haven't taken effect inside AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a route 53 record es-1.example.in and it is used by a node js Lambda function. Now, the A record for es-1.example.in is changed in route53 and TTL is set 300s. But the change has not been taken effect inside lambda and the lambda functions throw a connection error. What could be the possible problem?

Comment: So the TTL did not take effect and your lambda still uses old A record value?

Comment: Yea but only inside lambda. I can see the route 53 change effect in EC2 machines